# Text in columns after floating image

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing a paragraph and an image floating right from it.
The image is variable in size and relative to the viewport, so I can't use a fixed height for both the paragraph next to it and to image ("simulating" a floating picture).

Here is an example pen of the setup: https://codepen.io/etlaM/pen/vYvzEoQ

The styling of the image is as simple as follows:

```
.textimage {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

My customer would like to have the text split into two columns *after* the height of the floating image.

So basically a look like in a newspaper.

I don't think this is possible with pure CSS. But I wanted to ask you first before getting heights with JS.

Is there any way to style the elements (maybe structure them differently) to achieve the wanted look?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a table / columns or use a framework like bootstrap to do following:

```
.col-6   | .col-6
IMAGE | TEXT
---------------
.col-6   | . col 6
TEXT    | TEXT
```

Comment: You’ll need a little bit of JS but you won’t have to use heights. Put the img at the end and layout in 2 columns. You know then the content of the second column. Find the element at the top and move the img to just before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely can't do this with just css.

Alternatively, you can use `grid-auto-flow: column;` and add to the image accordingly `grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;`. But in this case you need to know how many rows we have (for example, if we have 10 elements, it will be `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto)`)... But the paragraphs will still not behave like columns!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#contentbox {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(5, auto);
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  gap: 0.75rem;
}

.textimage {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  max-width:100%;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentbox">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xtoLyW2.jpeg" class="textimage" />
  <p>The dog (Canis familiaris or Canis lupus familiaris) is a domesticated descendant of the wolf.</p>
  <p>Also called the domestic dog, it is derived from extinct Pleistocene wolves, and the modern wolf
   is the dog's nearest living relative.</p>
  <p>Dogs were the first species to be domesticated by hunter-gatherers 
   over 15,000 years ago before the development of agriculture. </p>
  <p>Due to their long association with humans, dogs have expanded to a large number of domestic individuals 
   and gained the ability to thrive on a starch-rich diet that would be inadequate for other canids.</p>
  <p>The dog has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, 
   and physical attributes.</p>
  <p>Dog breeds vary widely in shape, size, and color. They perform many roles for humans, such as hunting, 
   herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and the military, companionship, therapy, and aiding 
   disabled people.</p>
  <p>Over the millennia, dogs became uniquely adapted to human behavior, and the human–canine bond has 
   been a topic of frequent study.</p>
  <p>This influence on human society has given them the sobriquet of "man's best friend".</p>
  <p><small>Source: Wikipedia</small></p>
</div>
```

I suggest you use a minimum of js in combination with css variables:

```js
const detectImageSize = () => contentbox.style.setProperty('--img-height', contentbox.querySelector('.textimage').offsetHeight + 'px');

window.addEventListener('load', detectImageSize);
window.addEventListener('resize', detectImageSize);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.article {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: min(980px, 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#contentbox {
  --img-height: 0;
  --gap: 0.75rem;
  --p-margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: var(--gap);
  padding-top: calc(var(--img-height) + var(--p-margin));
}

.textimage {
  width: calc(50% - var(--gap) / 2);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp(16px, 1.5rem, 3vw);
  padding: 0;
  margin: var(--p-margin) 0;
}

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--img-height) - var(--p-margin));
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div id="contentbox">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xtoLyW2.jpeg" class="textimage" />
    <p>The dog (Canis familiaris or Canis lupus familiaris) is a domesticated descendant of the wolf.</p>
    <p>Also called the domestic dog, it is derived from extinct Pleistocene wolves, and the modern wolf
     is the dog's nearest living relative.</p>
    <p>Dogs were the first species to be domesticated by hunter-gatherers 
     over 15,000 years ago before the development of agriculture. </p>
    <p>Due to their long association with humans, dogs have expanded to a large number of domestic individuals 
     and gained the ability to thrive on a starch-rich diet that would be inadequate for other canids.</p>
    <p>The dog has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, 
     and physical attributes.</p>
    <p>Dog breeds vary widely in shape, size, and color. They perform many roles for humans, such as hunting, 
     herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and the military, companionship, therapy, and aiding 
     disabled people.</p>
    <p>Over the millennia, dogs became uniquely adapted to human behavior, and the human–canine bond has 
     been a topic of frequent study.</p>
    <p>This influence on human society has given them the sobriquet of "man's best friend".</p>
    <p><small>Source: Wikipedia</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was thinking exactly the same thing but used js to calculate the number of child elements `contexbox` had and use half that number rounded up in the `grid-template-rows: repeat(numberHere, auto))`

Comment: that's it! thank you so much for a clever way with minimal JS :)

Comment: I was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Newspaper structure with columns exist : [CSS multi-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_multicol_layout)

Use css property `column-count : ...`

Sanple code:

```css
article {
  font-size    : 14px;
  column-count : 2;
  width        : 46em;
  height       : 38em;
  }
article img {
  width      : 100%;
  padding    : 1.2em;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  }
article img + p {
  margin-top : 0;
  }
article p small {
  display    : inline-block;
  width      : calc( 100% - 2em );
  text-align : right;
  }
```

```html
<article>
  <p>The dog (Canis familiaris or Canis lupus familiaris) is a domesticated descendant of the wolf.</p>
  <p>Also called the domestic dog, it is derived from extinct Pleistocene wolves, and the modern wolf
    is the dog's nearest living relative.</p>
  <p>Dogs were the first species to be domesticated by hunter-gatherers 
    over 15,000 years ago before the development of agriculture. </p>
  <p>Due to their long association with humans, dogs have expanded to a large number of domestic individuals 
    and gained the ability to thrive on a starch-rich diet that would be inadequate for other canids.</p>
  <p>The dog has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, 
    and physical attributes.</p>
  <p>Dog breeds vary widely in shape, size, and color. They perform many roles for humans, such as hunting, 
    herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and the military, companionship, therapy, and aiding 
    disabled people.</p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/837/200/200" alt="dog">
  <p>Over the millennia, dogs became uniquely adapted to human behavior, and the human–canine bond has 
    been a topic of frequent study.</p>
  <p>This influence on human society has given them the sobriquet of "man's best friend".</p>
  <p><small>Source: Wikipedia</small></p>
</article>
```

Comment: Yes, the multi-column layout seems like the perfect solution, but it is not quite what I need:
When structuring and styling the elements like this, the img has to be placed at the appropriate position between the paragraphs to be properly shown on the right side.

This would require JS to find out the text's length etc to dynamically place the img at the right place.

My question was if there was a solution with an img and a parapgrah, where no lengths and dimensions are given, to achieve the same look.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result by getting rid of the float and reversing the order of the first two elements in the row. So your image will be set as `order: 2` and your first paragraph will be set as `order:1` while all other paragraphs will be set as `order:3`. You need the last one as the default is `order:0`. Here is the example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        #contentbox {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 1rem;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            align-items: stretch;
            gap: 0.75rem;
        }

        #contentbox > * {
            flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 0.75rem);
        }
        /* Add this */
        #contentbox p:first-of-type{
            order: 1
        }

        .textimage {
            width: 50%;
            order: 2; /* Keep this */
        }

        p {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            align-self: center; /* This is optional for better paragraph content positioning  */
            order:3; /* Add this */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentbox">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xtoLyW2.jpeg" class="textimage" />
    <p>The dog (Canis familiaris or Canis lupus familiaris) is a domesticated descendant of the wolf.</p>
    <p>Also called the domestic dog, it is derived from extinct Pleistocene wolves, and the modern wolf
        is the dog's nearest living relative.</p>
    <p>Dogs were the first species to be domesticated by hunter-gatherers
        over 15,000 years ago before the development of agriculture. </p>
    <p>Due to their long association with humans, dogs have expanded to a large number of domestic individuals
        and gained the ability to thrive on a starch-rich diet that would be inadequate for other canids.</p>
    <p>The dog has been selectively bred over millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities,
        and physical attributes.</p>
    <p>Dog breeds vary widely in shape, size, and color. They perform many roles for humans, such as hunting,
        herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and the military, companionship, therapy, and aiding
        disabled people.</p>
    <p>Over the millennia, dogs became uniquely adapted to human behavior, and the human–canine bond has
        been a topic of frequent study.</p>
    <p>This influence on human society has given them the sobriquet of "man's best friend".</p>
    <p><small>Source: Wikipedia</small></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to keep your html and css as close to your existing structure to make refactoring as easy as possible without rewriting the entire page as I know it can be difficult if you don't have full control of the styling.

Comment: This isn’t laying the paragraphs out in the order a newspaper would do it. It also assumes only the text of the first paragraph, and exactly that, should be alongside the image.

Comment: @AHaworth the paragraphs are in the order in the OP's code pen which had styling of `flex-flow: row wrap`. This is true to OP's codepen intentions. When they said "*So basically a look like in a newspaper*" I did not want to assume paragraphs would flow top-bottom/left right as the code pen did not. Hopefully OP can clarify.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort @jQueeny 
Unfortunately, A Haworth is right in his assumption. Sorry for not being clear enough.

The idea is to have as much text as there is space next to the image, next to it and _after_ the image the text turns into the newspaper-column-structure.

Comment: @etlaM  Thank you for confirming. Let me have a think...

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer but I can advice to use Masonry Grid Layout or Creative Text Flows using css clip-path shapes.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a table / columns or use a framework like bootstrap to do following:

```
.col-6   | .col-6
IMAGE    | TEXT
---------------
.col-6   | .col 6
TEXT     | TEXT
```